# How to print the location of Heap using java for a process?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I want to test if ASLR which randomizes the location of a heap for a process actually works.

Comment: What sort of attack can you get in Java which ASLR would help you with?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible to differentiate ASLR and non ASLR predictability using java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in pure Java.

- Machine address (pointers) are not exposed to Java applications.
- Even if they did, there's no Java API that tells you were the heap is.

I suppose that you could use the values returned by `System.identityHashcode()` as ersatz machine addresses.  If you wrote a simple Java test application that examined identity hashcode of a sample object, then ran it multiple times with ASLR enabled and disabled, you might observe a difference in predictability.

Comment: Currently testing with System.identityHashcode() Maybe I can run this on Vista and Windows 7 and compare ASLR predictability? I think ASLR is better implemented in Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

You can call `Unsafe.allocateMemory(size)` on some JVMs. This returns a memory location.

I don't recommend you do that and I don't recommend you worry about ASLR with Java.

Comment: It should be noted that `Unsafe` is usually `sun.misc.Unsafe` and is a JVM-specific class. That's **definitely** not standard API ;-)

Comment: Won't Unsafe.getUnsafe() throw a SecurityException if it's not called from a class from the bootstrap class loader?

Comment: @Paul Cager, You cannot use `getUnsafe()` to get an instance of `Unsafe` I figure if you cannot work out how to get an instance another way, you shouldn't be using Unsafe. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with JNI.  Allocate an array of longs the size of your heap or just smaller and call the JNI test method.

```
package com.example.aslrtest;

public class Test {
    private static native void test(long[] heapa);

    public void doTest()
    {
        long[] a=new long[size_of_available_heap/8];
        for (long i=0; i!=a.length; i++)
            a[i]=i;
        test(a);
        System.out.println(a[0]);
    }
}
```

Then with something like this JNI code, you can get the address of that array.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_aslrtest_Test_test(JNIEnv * env, jclass jc, jlongArray heapa)
{
  jlong* heapp;
  jboolean jniNoCopy = JNI_FALSE;
  heapp = (*env)->GetLongArrayElements(env, heapa, &jniNoCopy);
  heapp[0] = (jlong)heapp;
  (*env)->ReleaseLongArrayElements(env,heapa,heapp,0);
}
```

When this code returns, the first element of the array should contain the address of the array.

Whether doing this makes sense is another question.  Depends what you're doing.  I'm guessing probably not, but that's your call.