# Location of an object in memory using Java?

Tags: java

I used a simple test code and created an object in Java.

I used the System.identityHashCode function to get the roughly equivalent address.
Please see this question I asked for more context:
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819651/how-to-print-the-location-of-heap-using-java-for-a-process)

```
Start
```

1220081709
164644435
164644435
1220081709
1714981267
164644435
1220081709
164644435
164644435
1739421607
1714981267
1789308653
1714981267
1714981267
164644435
164644435
1220081709
1220081709
2094048729
164644435
764062238
1789308653
1697022030
1118942403
550670442
1611083771
2011117821
1612097414
1867546546
233814070
1965484127
1298264335
1494824825
109647522
304933128
1115100554
405223709
924232526
826845731
429521180
1269934693
2099901365
1295986757
1870277025
1027818036
179274584
148376547
536111262
1728081269
1293046055
1838022392
90080249
2773808
1522234469
1222033772
188006096
870010735
54270722
1594958326
1573703228
821556544
1728468445
1357862146
280371153
618846953
697436650
852031224
667823572
1361235382
1139773783
623839641
857681633
1144967167
2009698649
1382393727
265792796
413536612
1052756192
555551311
2039470468
1393665909
738794734
172647384
434175791
43086831
458379578
961725657
1761189877
1551156138
1977220433
981863753
919753123
703447155
938857350
1813126941
431546457
949026880
933725891
1468041408
932323873
1526644999
187883837
962687369
744814285
411509632
1345041684
1702714666
158311540
9814147
1737611457
405642246
1516132944
1752918153
2114727925
1377877625
1673077774
267273800
1682450723
1032121412
1639154665
1352230939
125955572
1663906309
741284129
1209719856
1533933643
281555666
1199604121
1169983611
1554278145
761700907
757124182
1145518399
536836638
1034573819
2054569821
1765421434
1803974286
1221696456
961187025
1298336441
559226720
1535043768
1759557365
2030814365
1939430784
1506392522
1254402771
900409598
2014336824
2026789660
868206906
1949571424
141437242
2018812712
2091111631
1743299062
1507939013
1476473244
912270823
1649966228
526060285
305035296
684754483
303731508
246826037
1614281502
2068291563
458505352
928125628
1833701635
485561348
391717236
1554207397
1720122918
681026912
2078955121
1439781957
569616903
69190395
1094315738
1114655658
1517791225
1706359509
1287645725
1268989256
1242327235
1957822511
1378503043
2046227094
1135645800
2111789711
1387438808
1306606930
2122381935
1169804875
697745840
1753620260
1030138392
522792230
1213409733
1272670619
837969413
554167265
252645816
643059393
1761506447
429297187
1800251636
932143669
645440018
970481529
744758938
1628776250
868385441
655241875
354051309
2010648173
161174419
881581266
1246657009
1713890131
1153274506
2044708167
1376843475
1471987900
689021860
1158576396
959260223
1126829932
2119867878
1865721816
1777831665
2076812944
1943435117
87740549
1481625201
1601866242
1710930502
802913784
1932213587
466046775
975286816
2050322608
1249472894
1795829092
1764374306
1384763166
1434248423
2056791433
449348672
1650627452
901833818
181398600
1486975107
1323423210
1285758491
1762502123
2131238190
1840511017
1114211331
492438277
8146001
432162720
569140886
658707264
614785763
1160493024
959772314
1143608781
654141617
1189367926
928946006
589409152
2005037700
355235176
433064372
690820521
1323900765
722090788
749784719
197731637
1118421150
379905859
608889682
849307419
2133473171
749131038
2096216952
1649083229
717881621
873275301
1234740309
1145892402
380254118
19627754
1318663487
745988969
827070797
2064721795
590956692
97255069
330889316
1421571929
1603837828
487638052
935143012
1663273938
850442967
1891275584
1763281041
190127487
17007273
225912260
156265924
2136368034
10969598
1829923591
1412485250
1355362812
1223737555
906199566
542081238
1133736492
86821213
1062730578
691332347
1336225759
1709834834
1715374531
331781542
1384828782
389572888
2021372560
17320380
1193334315
1020052872
666665703
1228283922
7578443
669356328
1352461710
1857040122
1893488603
302785728
1530970753
2023870964
1205807115
197005066
1791844235
1362875764
792386646
1096264275
1651462312
2048423956
1551083435
755301112
569951967
1405643749
186888796
1418902458
1835195318
1967571412
2019524978
1177264411
1516115866
1465888207
1250696665
888911819
2044693401
1128671313
855703640
113093521
239779852
1300650792
801818331
700804192
1615734796
724000057
626614097
243323391
727368649
1407965019
545768040
820791943
1762721320
1520314875
1171672119
2015744690
2066473405
2112978551
2040919865
2131361171
1759969037
359851081
703168415
549041464
2654289
1660962283
653163028
1922091779
27832
467772424
2060982148
15735326
323135501
2099705691
154777486
742510685
349610078
381322754
800323830
1352529649
851407248
918077175
453076530
2027711095
1322379422
922682751
549581070
481877743
758393764
1008546603
554330850
854535264
1951034559
1110027070
1034524001
1217278695
1873805543
202077946
1152392515
105987312
1064809421
1270708296
69461457
1355087478
891166311
1281234799
894738324
1186515174
227383376
1258992419
729212242
180977865
858132903
139527469
2133512606
1411915083
362500631
136998678
434311562
177506381
494959784
1584924857
444914211
135085423
490489482
1614486788
1223566071
171551625
1345107101
654694538
1892376585
940452025
697542255
479450812
771153740
717098535
596850781
374961130
1254691612
1459992991
954049115
1590567303
788223665
1996002959
979682126
760370133
2013125681
998462082
714994516
1741825447
363211825
1352618001
188855665
116331389
971536153
1289955330
1431814845
1957835280
1593111626
600987386
1179404661
980075617
931322429
1875244867
770476297
68732269
1984526644
1370784151
564660841
524518594
163638423
1491907201
465264835
718123118
637148086
1194417460
2044601711
1735121130
1500389297
1289931605
1033068770
381531395
11985823
1729747990
1388338491
1395193582
644591081
1734782899
110708174
951442116
724408050
1041301507
1310188746
44937684
1500894891
1197515375
424167941
1492359994
1632905845
1555011902
209052924
269247176
489242803
2136389305
368471295
1701700764
297529802
1241451998
132616134
1938822199
2015322662
1415899750
760805843
746169063
1706427008
274617771
558519794
391156721
723566380
1927739346
429405933
1480462011
1379484735
766488133
1759136625
1401888126
1490642445
683347213
274064735
2001061977
107251772
841752171
1853955208
1584946533
809222743
592705150
1566301264
970799122
1787577195
513694835
784830905
808460461
665933458
1806344089
248786184
198733779
781552568
1544025324
241230120
2052984951
898315108
1171981746
777194738
1316420512
1703013790
890721314
244621161
1064152569
968414967
371789756
1640499969
340435150
797130442
1368348708
434359633
985435678
823554482
948074059
2099532520
1539259783
1751161119
501544898
591786211
1154079020
533789436
1359857333
1601224357
1660187542
516992923
381221099
1239291892
334936591
724646150
748080913
1626635253
1391870861
571253872
1811924614
1698873038
16579154
1620450815
529236451
2147249730
363524275
161514210
149997662
2012387303
1473444918
1554803269
997525387
4347180
48610262
948887574
739893596
1461351842
169937755
2138081422
890594303
257430931
1609592259
565595754
1205215856
997133288
2004273875
402530283
752978331
185677346
385415131
861427365
1822459128
511307135
1456946298
1287887392
1035719231
1978156482
1681653767
522583802
2005327631
933138199
180636552
1564136253
1090681244
159257116
869724450
1685129668
959993440
565106169
1566695349
1151734776
1936269821
2067178556
1079549526
2047033626
1806127242
899205949
1111960904
1324217334
1747698677
290340673
672845127
2006648034
1650314950
2092063645
563929184
1112461277
1144051757
1656788308
1368125554
978777649
591210723
71786792
1782287177
1798675483
211543962
1333933549
1839367010
1214238505
169456094
485255936
1701108693
1084010740
1864729679
135370635
989080272
1948703724
590388871
1291305757
506121317
198249052
1224680467
1721336021
1742296210
1832874625
1618389807
249613347
1215960438
1192696614
1039630400
1141180808
649388699
763970039
239720060
295726648
1000613778
371327189
308587341
254432682
610145197
475911554
1416386650
354199555
207251401
55821173
1883584519
1348570406
880403204
774321798
275558166
1331353030
1418257117
1726367366
404765745
1817166166
1746807975
352697688
735176496
1637947081
383719474
279807577
1884243356
1684225630
798212303
223833712
1729331687
833984911
158635208
1154734929
820233764
971341455
165149691
1121984713
143167084
1027496148
1211753909
1360524062
2069520425
1784636163
475893892
1119541416
2028347345
1278414937
745957924
305297482
796347291
1090831733
541042092
848678846
158981348
529858968
1872474714
1457155060
501583032
1232704349
1287251034
1077868560
1712325475
625904878
1208381540
515693101
9949215
1860215686
1578101576
1730147382
1658468894
1696447045
45104096
2814081
51619133
2126858590
1247017815
1335505632
344078580
1902716336
774471675
647057258
234146798
1115192682
1953619005
1597138052
1701136111
1544825066
797592032
536357250
1567434291
686231088
1498711626
1010602519
748372710
88416491
2104764160
1420603736
363803606
561263033
1399618007
1991458058
1902942311
277466206
1187526605
46635017
2110683211
2117846131
98474692
1501740254
373145787
808992869
1024180126
1313946977
932500338
197524960
1939768105
733295628
90969663
2066253024
556518731
1119029232
2010005445
96263158
839710315
1896219768
1108319296
249253794
1615404108
1608577782
695149991
1074859057
523732435
1983049639
169081233
627418050
870459580
1155557696
1763576851
866838863
431709193
1536647185
790899473
1871151428
691523728
257798932
1352134125
646286321
161910521
368345698
1738275632
831013236
1753301011
2106971390
2010296347
690485778
2140326105
2109759485
1625168778
367145653
896472140
261989628
918201446
394215580
594202065
955147905
730578010
1660604171
1076825585
1362913826

```
End
```

Now the question is, how do I know the above numbers generated are caused by ASLR. I am using Windows 7 and cannot switch ASLR off.

In other words if ASLR is switched off do you think I will get the same number generated each time I run the code?

Sample code I used:

```
//
public class HashCodeTest {

public int hashCode() { return 0xDEADBEEF; }

public static void main(String[] argv) {
HashCodeTest o1 = new HashCodeTest();

System.out.println("First: " + o1);

System.out.println("Using System.identityHashCode():");
System.out.println("First: " + System.identityHashCode(o1));

}
}
```

EDIT:

What am I trying to accomplish?
I want to see if Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) is more effective in Windows 7 than in Windows Vista
I want to plot a frequency distribution curve or use some other statistical tools on the data to see if it is more predictable in one OS compared to the other for ALL applications in general.

Comment: Regarding your edit: are you trying to test if ASLR is more effective *for Java applications* in Windows 7, or just trying to test of ASLR is more effective *for applications in general*?  If the former, then I posit that it is equally ineffective in all cases; if the latter, then Java is the wrong language to be using for such a test.

Comment: For all applications in General.

Comment: Then you should be doing your test in C or another close-to-the-metal language, not in Java, which tries to be as far away from the actual operating system as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the person who suggested that the OP should use `identityHashcode()` values as **ersatz** memory addresses.  My idea is that, though they are not real memory addresses, they are based on the memory address of the object in question when `identityHashcode()` is first called ... on a typical JVM implementation.  This makes them a reasonable proxy for real memory addresses, for the purposes of THIS experiment.

My answer to the OP is that those results strongly suggest that ASLR is either not enabled, or it is not effective in randomizing the actual addresses of Java objects.

I would expect a certain amount of natural unpredictability in the object address because of non-deterministic factors in the JVM bootstrap sequence.  That is why you are seeing 3 or 4 different hashcode values for that object in different runs.  However, the fact that you are seeing certain values repeatedly strongly suggests that there is no systematic randomization happening.  In other words, no ASLR.

Strictly speaking, we should examine the JVM source code to check that `identityHashcode` is really reporting something that *would* change if ASLR was effective ... but I don't have time right now.

---

(FWIW: I agree with other people who have answered / commented that ASLR is not needed for Java anyway.  Modulo some unpatched bug in the JVM native code, a Java JVM simply does not allow a sandboxed Java program to inject executable (native) code.  And even a privileged Java program could only do this via a custom native library.)

Comment: I put more data. I think there is significant randomization. See edit

Comment: @redmave - maybe, but I can still see a lot of repetition in the first 2 or 3 lines.  You'd need to sort / count those numbers to see how much randomization is actually occurring.

Answer (score 6):

In general, in Java the `identityHashCode()` function does not specify anything about memory addresses. The only specified thing is that **these numbers are constant over the whole lifetime of an object**, and that *they are different for different objects as much as possible*.

- On 64-bit VMs with enough memory you can create more than 2^32 objects at once, thus even the second condition can not mean "always different for different objects".
- Modern Sun VMs are using a generational garbage collector, which means that objects are moved during their lifetime. The memory address then changes, while the identity hash code has to be the same - thus it can't be always the memory address.

Thus, you can't rely on anything beside the condition mentioned above.
On some VMs (especially old ones with non-moving garbage collectors) the number might be something which could be converted in C to the memory address (or the initial address when the object was created), but another valid implementation would be pseudo-random numbers given on object creation, or a simple counter.

Comment: @Paulo: The documentation says that it has integer mapping of memory location. " As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.) "

Comment: @redmave: have a look at the last phrase - **this implementation technique is not required by the Java programming language**. It might be, but does not have to be. In your example it might be some direct mapping of memory addresses, but as I explained in my answer, it can't always be done this way, so you should not rely on this.  Of course, in a normal program you don't need this property, you only need the first sentence. For the applications in your special problem, the answer from Stephen seems good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Address space layout randomization (ASLR) is:

- not necessary for Java applications
- unlikely to be helpful for Java applications
- actively defeated by the memory management techniques of many JVM implementations

Sun's JVM, for example, will allocate a large section of virtual memory at startup time (presumably using the OS heap functions to grab a single large block), and then proceed to manage that memory as its own heap in a very well-known way.  That is, the Eden, Survivor spaces, Tenured heap, and PermGen are all laid out the same way, and I'm pretty certain ASLR can't do anything about that.

However, the hacking techniques that ASLR is attempting to prevent simply aren't possible in Java anyway, for several reasons:

1. Most JVM implementations frequently copy objects from one location to another in memory.  Therefore, it is impossible to predict with any certainty where any object will be at any point in time.
2. It is not possible for Java code to allocate arbitrary-sized objects on the Java stack, so stack overruns are not possible.
3. It is impossible to subvert the Java Memory Model from within Java code; the only code for which this is possible is platform-native code invoked via JNI.  (Or `sun.misc.Unsafe`, which is an unsafe wrapper for basically the same thing.) Therefore, as long as you use the Java `SecurityManager` features correctly, no rogue process is capable of writing to *any* dangerous memory location anyway.

Perhaps you should describe what you are trying to accomplish and why you think that ASLR will help you accomplish it.  I'm pretty sure that (a) ASLR isn't having any effect on your Java programs, and (b) that's OK, because you don't really want it anyway.